# Adobe Reader - Content Preparation progress

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I was wondering recently if is it just me or anyone else noticed it:
why Adobe Reader after opening every single document displays "Content preparation" window with progress bar and it lasts for ages.. ?

On linux pdf readers work hell lot better (faster), on windows other readers also work faster. Some years back in the past Adobe Reader also used to be quick. What has happened? PDF files aren't bigger/more complex compared to 3-4 years ago. Computers are at least dual core and with much more ram and displaying pdf files is getting slower and slower..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be changed by going to:

-Edit -> Preferences -> Reading
-Under 'Screen Reader Options' select 'Only read the currently visible pages'

[image]

Comment: Thx. I've discovered this recently myself while setting accessibility setting for the new installation of Adobe Reader X.

Answer (score 6):

There are three solutions that will help:

To modify preferences, Edit > Preferences >

1. Accessibility > Other > UNCHECK Enable Assistive Technology support)
2. Internet > UNCHECK Display in Read Mode by default
3. Reading > Screen Reader Options > Select "Only read the currently visible pages"

Comment: #1 works great if you never want to use Screen Reading.  
#3 works great if you do want to use Screen Reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "Content Preparation Progress" window appears if Adobe Reader detects any kind of assistive technology connected to your computer.

This includes any alternatives to mice, for example Wacom tablets.

To completely disable this action, you need to delete (or rename) the plug-in "Accessibility.api", which is found in

```
 %PROGRAMFILES%\Adobe\Reader %version%\Reader\plug_ins\
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Acrobat XI.
Edit -> Preferences -> Accessibility -> Other Accessibility Options
Uncheck "Assistive Technology Support"

It works for me. Good luck!

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.